# How to create custom tag helper containing other tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

```
public class FormControlTextBoxHelper:TagHelper
{

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            writer.Write(@"<div class=""form-group"">");

            //Here I want to write <label asp-for="InputModel.Title" class="control-label"></label> and other tag helpers

            writer.Write(@"</div>");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

I could not found for 1-2 hours any information how to have custom tag helper which is containing other tag helpers. The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) show really simple examples which doesn't contain a lot of meaningful information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figure it out after reading multiple different articles which had part of the answer.

So first you need to have inject in the constructor of the tag helper `IHtmlGenerator`, which will generate the tag helper html, also generation of the elements requires ViewContext, which you can have only have as a property with `Attribute` `ViewContext`.

This is the summary of `ViewContext` attribute:

> Summary:
>
> Specifies that a tag helper property should be set with the current Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext
>     when creating the tag helper. The property must have a public set method.

The code look likes this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("form-control-text-box")]
public class FormControlTextBoxHelper:TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public FormControlTextBoxHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            writer.Write(@"<div class=""form-group"">");

            var label = _generator.GenerateLabel(
                            ViewContext, 
                            For.ModelExplorer, 
                            For.Name, null, 
                            new { @class = "control-label" });

            label.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            var textArea = _generator.GenerateTextBox(ViewContext, 
                                For.ModelExplorer, 
                                For.Name, 
                                For.Model, 
                                null, 
                                new { @class = "form-control" });

            textArea.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            var validationMsg = _generator.GenerateValidationMessage(           
                                    ViewContext, 
                                    For.ModelExplorer, 
                                    For.Name, 
                                    null, 
                                    ViewContext.ValidationMessageElement, 
                                    new { @class = "text-danger" });

            validationMsg.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            writer.Write(@"</div>");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

So this tag helper called like `<form-control-text-box asp-for="InputModel.Title"></form-control-text-box>` will produce the html which is equal to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="InputModel.Title" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="InputModel.Title" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I hope I help someone to figure it out faster.

Comment: Thank you @mybirthname, this was quite useful. There's plenty of articles showing how to create tag helpers displaying data, but not much information on how to create helpers with input elements.